# What happens to the network if a bunch of stake goes offline?

Tags: consensus

say like all the underwater internet cables got cut and north america lost internet access with the rest of the world (lol). assuming north america had > 1/3 stake on solana and eth, is the following true?

1. solana would halt, then come back online once the cables get repaired (or come back as a fork before cables get repaired if there's people want to do that)
2. ethereum would fork, and then eventually once the cables were repaired, validators would starting building on top of the biggest chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to how Ethereum works, but for Solana, the network would start forking, but it wouldn't be able to root any blocks, since it's impossible to get 2/3 stake weight to vote on any block.

The network would keep processing transactions, sending blocks, voting, etc, but none of the transactions would really "land" since no roots are being created.

In the current implementation, the validator holds onto all forks in memory, so if there's longterm forking, the process runs out of memory and OOMs.  Theoretically, the network could come back once the cable is repaired, but that wouldn't happen until work is done to cache forks on disk rather than in memory.